# Use Specific Path for Loading Haml/Erb

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to be able to pass a specific route in my web app. Its a good size (and growing) sinatra app.

what I have

```
get '/' do
  haml :Hello_World
end
```

what I want

```
get '/' do
  haml :/specific/path/Hello_World
end
```

I realize I could change the root directory with
`set :views, settings.root + '/my/path'`

But this really isn't a preferable option because I need multiple specific routes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have a symbol that contains forward slashes you need to surround it with quotes. So if you want to render a view in a directory just surround the path with quotes. So your example would become...

```rb
get '/' do
  haml :'/specific/path/Hello_World'
end
```